# Do we say a matrix $A$ is positive definite on $\mathbb{R}^n$ or $\mathbb{R}^n \times \mathbb{R}^n$

Tags: soft-question, proof-writing, article-writing

Suppose $A$ is positive definite, such that for all $x \in \mathbb{R}^n$, we have:

$$x^TAx > 0$$

Do we say $A$ is positive definite on $\mathbb{R}^n$ or $\mathbb{R}^n \times \mathbb{R}^n$

Comment: On $\Bbb R^n$ because the operator is defined *on* $\Bbb R^n$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remember that $x^T$ is the transpose of the vector $x$, so ultimately, the input is just one vector in $\mathbb{R}^n$. Think about the quadratic form as $q(x) = \langle Ax,x\rangle$.

Answer (score 1):

On $\mathbb{R}^n$ makes more sense to me since that's what $A$ is acting on.

Looking at the Google search results for *"positive definite on"*, whenever the context is linear algebra it seem to always mention the vector space next.